# Declaring an array 100x100 or 99x99

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering when you declare an array in Java, it starts at 0 then 1, 2.. etc.
So if I want a two dimensional array at 100x100, will it be

```
int [] [] a; 
a = new int [99] [99]
```

or would I keep the 100?

Comment: For things such as these, refer to the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also if the arrays is zero based the size is not affected by that.

It means that

```
int[][] a = new int[100][100];
```

Has size 100 x 100, while indexes for each dimension are from 0 to 99 inclusive.
So the last valid element is a[99][99].

Answer (score 3):

```
 int[][] a = new int[100][100]
```

Confusing, I know.